# Comparing object arrays in C++

Tags: c++

Although I've heard they're outdated, my professor is insisting we work exclusively with pointers, C-Strings, and arrays.

In this program, sets (arrays) are created by the user and I have to create a constructor, copy constructor, and overload the + function (to create a union set), * (to create an intersection set), =, == (to determine if two sets have same numbers), and ostream.

I am very puzzled over the +, ==, and optional [] overloading operators I created and I'm quite sure they're wrong, though I get no errors. It's been a while since I've done Java (was hospitalized for a while w/ no classes), so this switch has been incredibly fast for me, so I am very new. Attached is the code I have so far... I've been working on this for about sixteen hours this week :(

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

class IntegerSet {
    private:
    int ARRAY_SIZE;
    bool *a;
    int* trueCount = 0;
    int* ptr;

public:
    IntegerSet(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            ARRAY_SIZE = n;
            a = new bool[ARRAY_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE+1; i++) 
{
                a[i] = false;
             }

    }
    else {
        cout << "Please enter a number greater than 0!" << endl;
    }
}

IntegerSet();

void insert(int n) {
    if (n > -1 && n < ARRAY_SIZE) {
        a[n] = true;
        trueCount++;
        cout << n << " was added to the set." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not insert. Number was out of set scope. Try again." << endl;
    }
}

void remove(int n) {
    if (n > -1 && n < ARRAY_SIZE) {
        if (a[n] == true) {
            a[n] = false;
            cout << "Number " << n << " was deleted from the set." << endl;
            trueCount--;
        }
        else {
            cout << n << " was not a part of the set (already false)." << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Number out of scope. Try again." << endl;
    }
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, const IntegerSet& set);
IntegerSet(const IntegerSet& obj);
void printOn(ostream &out) const;

IntegerSet operator+(IntegerSet set) {
    
    int len = set.ARRAY_SIZE;
    IntegerSet a3(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (this[i] == true) {
            a3.insert(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < set.ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (set[i] == true) {
            a3.insert(i);
        }
    }

    return a3;

}

bool operator==(IntegerSet set) {
    if (this->ARRAY_SIZE != set.ARRAY_SIZE) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < set.ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (this[i] == true && set[i] == false || this[i] == false && set[i] == true) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
     
}

   /* IntegerSet& operator=(const IntegerSet&) {

   }*/

int& operator[](int index) {
    if (index >= this->ARRAY_SIZE) {
        cout << "Array index out of bounds, exiting!";
        exit(0);
    }
    return ptr[index];
}

};


IntegerSet::IntegerSet(const IntegerSet& obj)
    : ARRAY_SIZE(obj.ARRAY_SIZE) {
a = new bool[ARRAY_SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    a[i] = obj.a[i];
    if (a[i] == true) {
        trueCount++;
    }
}

}


void printMenu() {
    cout << "1. View the set." << endl;
    cout << "2. Add a number to the set." << endl;
    cout << "3. Delete a number from the set." << 
endl;
    cout << "4. Copy the set (copying will create a 
second set to allow more options)." << endl;
}

void printMenuTwo() {
    cout << "1. View your sets." << endl;
    cout << "2. Add to set 1." << endl;
    cout << "3. Add to set 2." << endl;
    cout << "4. Delete from set 1." << endl;
    cout << "5. Delete from set 2." << endl;
    cout << "6. Create a new set that is a union of 
the two sets." << endl;
cout << "7. Create a new set that is an intersection of the two sets." << endl;
cout << "8. Determine whether the two sets have the same length." << endl;
cout << "9. Determine whether the two sets have the same numbers." << endl;
cout << "10. Check if set one is a subset of set two." << endl;
}


 void IntegerSet::printOn(ostream &out) const {
if (trueCount == 0) {
    out << "---";
}
else {
    out << a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        out << ", " << a[i];
    }

    out << "\n";
}
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm, const IntegerSet& set) {

set.printOn(strm);
return strm;
}

int main()
{

cout << "Enter size of set: ";
int size;
cin >> size;
IntegerSet a1(size);
cout << endl;
cout << "Set one created. It can now hold integers 0 through " << size-1 << endl;
cout << "Please choose an option from the given menu: " << endl;

while (true) {
    printMenu();
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Set: " << a1;
        cout << endl;
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Which number would you like to add to the set? "; 
        int number;
        cin >> number;
        a1.insert(number);
        cout << endl;
    }
    break;

    case 3:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Which number would you like to remove from the set? ";
        int number;
        cin >> number;
        a1.remove(number);
        cout << endl;
    }
    break;

    case 4:
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You have created a second set! It is a copy of your "
            << "original set. Feel free to manipulate both of these, if you "
            << "choose!";
    } goto exit_loop;
    break;

    default:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter a valid number!";
        break;
    } 
} exit_loop:;
    
    cout << endl;
    IntegerSet a2 = IntegerSet(a1);

    cout << endl;

    while (true) {
        printMenuTwo();
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Set 1: " << a1 << endl;
            cout << "Set 2: " << a2 << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Which number would you like to add to set 1? ";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            a1.insert(number);
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Which number would you like to add to set 2? ";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            a2.insert(number);
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 4:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Which number would you like to remove from set 1?";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            a1.remove(number);
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 5:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Which number would you like to remove from set 2?";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            a2.remove(number);
        }
        break;

        case 6:
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Set 3 has been created, as a union of the two sets." << endl;
            IntegerSet a3 = a1 + a2;
            cout << a3;
            cout << endl;
            goto exit_loop2;
        }
        break;

        case 7:
        {
      
        } 
        break;

        case 8:
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 9:
        {
            

            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 10:
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

        default:
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a number that corresponds with the given menu choices." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
    } exit_loop2:;
}
```

Comment: We already see, and know you're new, no need to state that in your questions title. Rather follow everything what you've being told in the [tour], and the [help]!

Comment: You need to be more specific. What's the problem with this code? What do you need help with?

Comment: Note: Pointers, arrays, etc... are not outdated. They are still very useful. But they should not be taught in an introductory course, or at least not at the beginning of one.

Comment: this is a very strange integer set, I would expect a size 4 set to be able to contain 1,94,-102 and 5. But no it only has flags saying if 0,1,2,3 are present. Are you sure thats the intent

Comment: Similarly `goto`. `goto` is surprisingly hard to get right and even when you do get it right it is astonishingly hard to convince people that A) you got it right and B) its usage is justified. I find I spent more time defending the use of `goto` the rare few times I believed it justified than I spent rewriting the code to not use it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the IntegerSet operator+(IntegerSet set) and bool operator== (IntegerSet set) seem to not be working correctly.

Comment: @pm100 it's integers 0 through whatever the user specifies. If the set is large enough, the number should be able to fit, but negative numbers aren't permitted.

Comment: Tactical note: If you are having trouble with only a small part of the code, back up the code and either carve it down to or make from scratch a small program that tests that small part. It's a lot easier to find bugs when you have little code for the bug to hide in.

Comment: @user4581301 good to know I'll try to avoid using that in the future. It's always just been my "go to" to getting out of C++ switches

Comment: i get that , but its a very odd definition of a set , in both maths and cs. Unless this is what the assignment specifies exactly you should get marked down

Comment: Tactical note: [Use all of the tools at your disposal to find mistakes](https://godbolt.org/z/33nEYnEc7). Compiler warnings are almost always your friend. They're the first line of defense against logic problems, so turn them on and turn them up loud so you can't ignore them.

Comment: @pm100 this is what the assignment says - an array of bools where numbers can be 0 through n. It is a bit strange of an assignment, yes.

Comment: An easy way to get out of a complicated loop without `goto` is to put the loop in its own function and return from the function where you would have put a `goto`.

Comment: @user4581301 both my + and == statements, the compiler gives me a warning says "==" unsafe mix of type 'int' and type 'bool' in operation.

Comment: thats because `operator[]` returns an int and you are comparing to a bool

Comment: Check the link. You'll see a LOT of mistakes being highlighted. Also pay attention to the compiler options I used `-O3` tells the compiler to optimize and when optimizeing, the compiler looks at the code much closer and spots more problems. `-fsanitize=undefined` hunts for bugs at runtime.  `-Wextra` and `-Wall` make the compiler increasingly picky.  `-pedantic` tells the compiler to keep an eye out for standard compliance. This helps you write more portable code.

Comment: Note: I don't know Visual Studio well enough to get this level of granularity out of Microsoft compilers.

Comment: @pm100 that helps a lot! Thanks!  I'm getting closer!

Comment: @user4581301 thanks I'm going through them now! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You'll find a lot of them are repeats. Figure out why `ptr` is uninitialized and about half of the warnings will just go away.

Answer (score 0):

consider to use parenthesis

```
(this[i] == true && set[i] == false) || (this[i] == false && set[i] == true)
```

or simply use

```
 this[i] != set[i]
```